# Pyomo constraint meaning

Tags: python, constraints, pyomo

I would like to ask you a question about the declaration of restrictions. In short, in order not to take up too much of your time, I would like to make the query in a practical way. Considering an expression of the following form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRVbL.png)

I would like to ask you if the following constraint approximation in Pyomo is correct:

```
#DECLARATION OF CONSTRAINTS
    #Demand balance and marginal costdef Demand_Bal_rule(m,n,s,p): 
    return sum((m.qt[t,n,s,p]) for t in m.t) + sum((m.qh[h,n,s,p] - m.b[h,n,s,p]) for h in m.h) == m.d[n,s,p].

m.Demand_Bal = Constraint(m.n, m.s, m.p, rule= Demand_Bal_rule)
```

I would like to ask you if in the input parameter declaration of the function (Demand_Bal_rule) you enter the model (m) and the rest of the indices (n,s,p) which would be equivalent to a mathematical "for all".  In the case of the input parameters of the Constraint function, the mathematical "for all" (n,s,p) is also given. Is this analysis correct?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

I was expecting that this was the correct declaration, however, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: the constraint formulation looks fine (except for the trailing "." at the end)